# Referencing controller variables in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

If a tweet contains any `phrase` that belongs to the current user's `blockedshow`, it receives the `redacted` div. I want the tooltip to tell the user which specific phrase the tweet contains, when it hovers over the tweet. Right now Im using `@phrases` and it's not working. Any ideas?

View

```
<% if is_redacted? tweet %>
    <!-- Tweet contains at least one blocked phrase. -->
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/#{tweet.user.screen_name}" 
       data-toggle="tooltip" title="This tweet contains the phrase:<%=@phrases%> "> 
        <%= check_if_redacted(tweet.text)%>
    </a>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
  class TwitterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login
  end

  def tweet
    text = params[:my_tweet]
     Client.update(text) unless text==nil

end

  private

  def is_redacted? tweet
    @phrases ||= current_user.blockedshows.map(&:phrases).flatten.map(&:text)
    @phrases.any? { |phrase| tweet.text.include? phrase }
  end

  helper_method :is_redacted?

end
```

Comment: What does it mean it's not working? `@phrases` are `nil`?

Comment: Yes, only "This tweet contains the phrase:" appears in the tooltip.

Comment: Add the code of the controller action as well.

Comment: looks like your are checking for `redacted` in two ways?

Comment: is this rails or some other framework?

Comment: @froderik this is rails

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable @phrases is defined in a helper method. I don't think it is visible in the view scope. You need to initate in the controller action instead. If this is in the index:

```
def index
  @phrases = current_user.blockedshows.map(&:phrases).flatten.map(&:text)
end
```

I am a bit confused by your `tweet` method. Is this a controller action or just a helper method. I looks like a helper method since you are referring to it in the view (unless there is more code not seen here). I would put tweet in an instance variable also and maybe even is_redacted. Seomthing like:

```
def index
  @phrases = current_user.blockedshows.map(&:phrases).flatten.map(&:text)
  @tweet = Client.update(params[:my_tweet]) unless text==nil
  @isredacted = @phrases.any? { |phrase| tweet.text.include? phrase }
end
```

and then use it in the view:

```
<% if @isredacted %>
  <!-- Tweet contains at least one blocked phrase. -->
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/#{@tweet.user.screen_name}" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" title="This tweet contains the phrase:<%=@phrases%> "> 
    <%= check_if_redacted(@tweet.text)%>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, now `@phrases` is not showing up nil. I can see all of the user's phrases in the tooltip. But how can I see the specific phrase that the tweet includes?

Comment: I don't know enough about your data model to answer that. It looks like you want the text of the tweet to match a phrase exactly. Is that so?